# Elasticsearch unexpected results when sorting against deeply nested attributes

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform some sorting based on the attributes of a document's deeply nested children.

Let's say we have an index filled with **publisher** documents. A `publisher` has a collection of **books**, and 
each `book` has a title, a published flag, and a collection of **genre scores**. A `genre_score` represents how well
a particular book matches a particular genre, or in this case a `genre_id`.

First, let's define some mappings (for simplicity, we will only be explicit about the nested types):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/book_index' -d '
  {
    "mappings": {
      "publisher": {
        "properties": {
          "books": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "genre_scores": {
                "type": "nested"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

Here are our two publishers:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/book_index/publisher/1' -d '
  {
    "name": "Best Books Publishing",
    "books": [
      {
        "name": "Published with medium genre_id of 1",
        "published": true,
        "genre_scores": [
          { "genre_id": 1, "score": 50 },
          { "genre_id": 2, "score": 15 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/book_index/publisher/2' -d '
  {
    "name": "Puffin Publishers",
    "books": [
      {
        "name": "Published book with low genre_id of 1",
        "published": true,
        "genre_scores": [
          { "genre_id": 1, "score": 10 },
          { "genre_id": 4, "score": 10 }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Unpublished book with high genre_id of 1",
        "published": false,
        "genre_scores": [
          { "genre_id": 1, "score": 100 },
          { "genre_id": 2, "score": 35 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }'
```

And here is the final definition of our index & mappings...

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/book_index/_mappings?pretty=true'
...
{
  "book_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "publisher": {
        "properties": {
          "books": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "genre_scores": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "genre_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "score": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "published": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now suppose we want to query for a list of publishers, and have them sorted by those who books performing 
well in a particular genre. In other words, sort the publishers by the `genre_score.score` of one of their books 
for the target `genre_id`.

We might write a search query like this...

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/book_index/_search?pretty=true' -d '
  {
    "size": 5,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
      {
        "books.genre_scores.score": {
          "order": "desc",
          "nested_path": "books.genre_scores",
          "nested_filter": {
            "term": {
              "books.genre_scores.genre_id": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "_source":false,
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "books",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": []
          }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "size": 5,
          "sort": []
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

Which correctly returns the Puffin (with a sort value of `[100]`) first and Best Books second (with a sort value of `[50]`).

But suppose we only want to consider books for which `published` is true. This would change our expectation to have Best Books first (with a sort of `[50]`) and Puffin second (with a sort of `[10]`).

Let's update our `nested_filter` and query to the following...

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/book_index/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
  "size": 5,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
      {
        "books.genre_scores.score": {
          "order": "desc",
          "nested_path": "books.genre_scores",
          "nested_filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "books.genre_scores.genre_id": 1
                  }
                }, {
                  "term": {
                    "books.published": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "_source": false,
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "books",
        "query": {
          "term": {
            "books.published": true
          }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
        "size": 5,
        "sort": []
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Suddenly, our sort values for both publishers has become `[-9223372036854775808]`.

Why does adding an additional term to our `nested_filter` in the top-level `sort` have this impact?

Can anyone provide some insight as to why this behavior is happening? And additionally, if there are any viable solutions to the proposed query/sort?

This occurs in both **ES1.x** and **ES5**

Thanks!

Comment: what version of es?

Comment: Happens on both ES 1.x and 5 -- will update my original post.